# Are there any composite/plastic lumber brands that can be used indoor?

Tags: plastic, lumber, composite

I need to build a platform/base in a partially finished basement that occasionally floods. The flood isn't much, about 1/2 inch, but it does stick around for a bit (at least until the dehumidifier takes care of it). Anything made of wood gets soaked enough to weaken the wood, and is probably a good home for mold. My first thought was to use plastic/composite lumber, as it can get wet without any damage, but I can't find information on what brands are suitable for indoor use. I've heard that some brands have gassing issues. Is there a brand suitable for indoor use?

Comment: I think it would be wise to do some research and try to find out where the water is entering. I would work on trying to fix the leak.

Comment: I know where it is coming from, it's an older house, and during heavy rains, the basement seeps water. I am working to address is, but no solution is going to be perfect.

Comment: I would consider aluminum tubing.

Comment: I would look into installing a sump pump, Water to either to the DWS or outside.  a platform could contribute to a health issue.  Water-moisture under the platform creating a condition that's encourage mold and other nasty's to grow under the platform.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your platform/base doesn't need to be structural, cellular PVC based decking/trim is acceptable for indoor use and that type of moisture exposure. Look at [Azek's trim product line](https://azek.com/products/trim/trimboard#traditional).